# Proving whether a function is injective...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I am confused on how to prove this function. It is $f(x)$ but within its set, it involves $y$.

For example, $f(x)=\{y \in \mathbb R:....\}$ (where the .... is an equation)

To prove its injectivity, would I just need to check if $x_1=x_2$ ? I do not know where the $y$ would come in because it is $f(x)$ and not $f(x,y)$.

Also, I do not think this will affect the answer but $f: \mathbb R \to S$ and $ S = \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I am still learning how to write using MathJax, forgive me if there is a wrong notation!

Comment: You managed the MathJax pretty well; the only thing that I’d change is your $....$ in the description of $f(x)$, for which I’d use $\ldots$ (`\ldots`).

Comment: To prove a function $f$ is one-to-one (injective), show that if $f(u) = f(v)$ implies $u = v$, or, equivalently, $u \neq v$ implies $f(u) \neq f(v)$.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott, I will work on the dots next time when I use them!

Comment: @SeanRoberson Oh okay, so the $y$ necessarily does not matter in terms of $f(x)$, but with $f(u) \neq f(v)$ . I may have worded this response weirdly, but I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: Get out of the habit of thinking that functions are ordered pairs strictly named $(x, y)$. Use $y$ as just another variable.